# Scroll to top feature

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, scrolltop

I'm trying to add a scroll to top feature on my site.

The script I'm using was put together by another developer, so I'm not sure if I'm using it properly.

This is my footer.php file (using wordpress) http://pastebin.com/vniCcaGr

Any ideas why it isn't working on my site (removed) ?

Comment: [is this the general idea you're trying to tackle?](http://jsfiddle.net/qsu5Z/)

Answer (score 3):

I have not seen your code, but using scrollTop will solve your problem.

```
jQuery("#id_of_scroll_to_top_button").click(function(){
   jQuery(document).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: If you have done "$x=jQuery.noConflict();" in your code then '$' might not work. So, I have used jQuery instead to be fullproof.

Comment: but why than you leave `$("#id_of_scroll_to_top_button")` ?

Comment: Corrected it. That was accidental.

Comment: you could do this: `(function($){ /*remap $ to jQuery*/ /*CODE HERE with bulletproof $ */ })(jQuery);` Unless you like to write over and over 'jQuery' in your code.

Comment: This was a small code snippet, so it would not matter writing jQuery as well. But if its for heavy use in the project, I will surely go for  remapping.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use a plugin called scrollTo, similar functionality to the native scrollTop but with much more options.

check it here: [scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)